# Binding name weblogic.management.home.localhome not able to see in weblogic 12c console

Tags: jmx, weblogic12c

We have upgraded weblogic server from 10.3.0 to 12.2.1.4
As JNDI name weblogic.management.home.localhome able to see in old weblogic but not in 12c.
Our application deployed correctly on 12.2.1.4 version without any error but not seeing this jndi.
Please suggest the solution - how we can available this jndi in weblogic 12.2.1.4 version?